# OpenLayers Google layer in japanese

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

[OpenLayers Google http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg31/scaled.php?server=31&filename=screenshot20120814at916.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg31/scaled.php?server=31&filename=screenshot20120814at916.png&res=landing)

I am working on an OpenLayers Map, with one OSM layer and one Google Hybrid. The problem is that all the towns are in Chinese/Japanese? Obviously I would like to have them in Dutch/English. Does anybody know what I did wrong? Here is where I load my map:

```
// add google aerial layer
var googleLayer     = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
     "satellite",
     {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 19}
);
window.map[page_id].addLayer(googleLayer);
googleLayer.mapObject.setTilt(0);
```

The markers also tend to move around when pannning the map. Is that fixable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google Maps [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics) you can enforce certain language by specifying language parameter when importing google maps script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
```

Try `language=en` to enforce english labels